# Avoid repeated values on SQL

Tags: sql

I want to join two tables, in which the relationship is one to many,
my problem is, only want the first result from each key (no_) of table header.

Here is the code

```
select th.No_, tl.fg
from TableHeader as th
left join TableLine as tl on th.No_ = tl.[LineNo_]
```

[image]

What I need, as result, is one `th.NO_` related to one FG
in other words, just bring the first FG match (of the second table) for each NO_ (first table).

For example:

| Column NO | Column FG |
| --- | --- |
| CNOC008617 | FG092405 |
| NOC008630 | FG092353 |
| NOC007854 | FG092356 |

Comment: _"the first FG match"_... by what ordering criteria?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `row_number()` window function. This will create a pseudo column of unique row for each No_ group. And then you can easily pick one of them. Now if you want to pick anything specific, you need to mention it in order by clause.

```
with TableHeader_CTE as (select th.*, row_number() over( partition by No_ order by No_) as rn from TableHeader th)
select th.No_, tl.fg
from TableHeader_CTE as th
left  join
TableLine as tl
on th.No_ = tl.[LineNo_]
Where TableHeader_CTE.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

sub query may work:

```sql
select 
  th.No_, 
  (select tl.fg from TableLine as tl where th.No_ = tl.[LineNo_] and rownum <= 1) as fg
from TableHeader as th
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below query.

Note:
Given sample data is inserted to table "tl"
use a rank function, group by clause, and CTE to get the required result.

```
with tmp_cte as
(
select tl.[no],tl.fg, rank() over( partition by tl.no order by tl.fg desc) as [rank] from tl
)
Select [no],fg from tmp_cte
group by [no],fg
having min(rank) = 1

Result:
  [no]        [fg]
NOC007677   FG082416
NOC007777   FG083584
NOC007780   FG083914
NOC007742   RPK067588
```